# Versioning API duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In my Ruby on Rails application I have my api routes looks like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }  do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
    resources :clients
  end
end
```

Now my response format for `users` resource will change so I want to create new api version: v2. My `clients` resource will not change, so I need to copy `jbuilder` templates and controllers to `v2` api namespace. This will be a duplication. Is there way to avoid that? Let say whenever someone tries to reach `api/v2/clients/*` I will redirect him to `api/v1/clients*`

Answer (score 1):

`routes.rb` is "just Ruby", so you should be able to make a simple loop to handle both versions:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }  do
  [:v1, :v2].each { |version|
    namespace version do
      resources :users
      resources :clients
    end
  }
end
```

This doesn't *redirect* (as you mentioned in your question), it just means your API returns the same result for both URLs. I think that's a simpler solution and it's arguably an antipattern, in most cases, to redirect API responses anyway.